# ARKit Draw 3D Curved Line

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to draw a curved 3D line (doesn't matter if it made by a cylinder, rectangle, etc) on a ARSCNView (Renders using SceneKit).

I currently have something like this which renders lines using SCNCylinder but not sure how to curve them.

I tried using SCNShape from UIBezierPath to no success. Because I already have 3d point points not 2D points and using this method I can't have different Y axis (aka up) in ARKit.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?